# Hiding files on FTP server

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I have an Ubuntu server and I run an FTP server on it. I changed its folder structure and want to restrict access of users to some of the files not all of them in a way that other files be hidden to users.

How can I do this?

Comment: It depends on ftp server. For example you can use `hide_file` option in `vsftpd` server. So which ftp daemon you're running?

Comment: Add more information to your question. What FTP server and version are you running?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of permissions. Supposing that your FTP directory is in `/srv/ftp`, first you should issue these two commands:

`find /srv/ftp -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

`find /srv/ftp -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;`

so that every file can be read and written by its owner only, and every directory can be read and written by its owner only, but can be explored by everyone.

Then, you can proceed in changing the ownership of files and directories. What should be visible through FTP will belong to the user `ftp`, while the rest will belong to `root` or any other user that is not `ftp`.